# Why is my SQLite Autoincrement query not working?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite and SQL in general, recently I've been trying to mess around and use the autoincrement function, I've done something wrong in my code because the autoincrement is not filling in the column at all (Just returns "None").

```py
import sqlite3

make_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (product_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name varchar(50), price int);"
c.execute(make_table)

insert_apple = "INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES ('apple', 2);"
c.execute(insert_apple)
insert_orange = "INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES ('orange', 2);"
c.execute(insert_orange)
insert_banana = "INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES ('banana', 3);"
c.execute(insert_banana)

select_products = "SELECT * FROM products;"
c.execute(select_products)
print(c.fetchall())
```

I already looked through the way to generally use AUTOINCREMENT but the error keeps repeating and I can't find my mistake, and didn't find any questions with the same problem. I saw people mentioning ROWID but none of the explanations felt thorough enough and explained how to use it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I Just tried making a dummy using the same technique of this and it worked, so it must be a typo somewhere in the code above.

Here is the full code of the dummy that did work:

```py
import sqlite3

try:
    connection = sqlite3.connect('SQLite_Python.db')
    c = connection.cursor()
    print("Database created and Successfully Connected to SQLite")

    create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name varchar(50), age INTEGER);"
    insert_data1 = "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ('John', 25);"
    insert_data2 = "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ('Jessica', 27);"
    c.execute(create_table)
    c.execute(insert_data2)
    c.execute(insert_data1)

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Error while connecting to sqlite", error)

select_data = "SELECT * FROM users;"
c.execute(select_data)
print(c.fetchall())
```

So my guess is that it is a typo, I will be closing this post down if it turns out to be so

Comment: What error are you getting?  What information is being printed out?

Comment: Are you sure that there wasn't already a table "products" with a different definition?

Comment: To expand on @MichaelButscher's comment, your sql statement has `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`.  If the table already exists, that sql statement will do nothing.  Did you perhaps create an early version of the table with an incorrect primary key column definition, and that version is still there?

Comment: @ewong The error was that when I printed out the table's contents, the id column would show 'None' in every row.

Comment: And it seems likely that what @MichaelButscher said is true after I tried recreating the program with the exact same statements on a new file, and it worked fine. So I just reset the database I was using and remade the table, everything worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```py
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('test')

with con:

    c = con.cursor()

    make_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (product_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name varchar(50), price int);"
    c.execute(make_table)

    insert_apple = "INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES ('apple', 2);"
    c.execute(insert_apple)
    insert_orange = "INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES ('orange', 2);"
    c.execute(insert_orange)
    insert_banana = "INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES ('banana', 3);"
    c.execute(insert_banana)

    select_products = "SELECT * FROM products;"
    c.execute(select_products)
    print(c.fetchall())
```

Result:

```
[(1, 'apple', 2), (2, 'orange', 2), (3, 'banana', 3)]
```

Comment: It seems that I had something in the database that was messing around with it, since I don't see any difference in the python part of things.

Comment: As others mentioned, one option is that the table already existed with another definition without the autoincrement. If you can remove the dabatase or the table to be sure, is something to try

Comment: Yes it seems that was the case after I tried removing the databse and recreating it